# Django template not rendering time correctly

Tags: django, django-templates

I have datetime object that I need to show in two different timezones. In the backend, I use `astimezone()` to change the original datetime tzinfo, this is the code:

```
print("event.date_start: %s" % event.date_start)
print("event.date_start.hour: %s" % event.date_start.hour)
print("event.date_start.tzinfo: %s" % event.date_start.tzinfo)

user_timezone = pytz.timezone("America/Guayaquil")
print("user_timezone: %s" % user_timezone)

event_user_timezone = event.date_start.astimezone(user_timezone)
print("event_user_timezone: %s" % event_user_timezone)
print("event_user_timezone.hour: %s" % event_user_timezone.hour)
```

This code prints the datetimes correctly, `event.date_start` is in UTC time, 18hrs - `event_user_timezone` is in "America/Guayaquil", 13hrs.

```
event.date_start: 2020-11-17 18:00:00+00:00
event.date_start.hour: 18
event.date_start.tzinfo: UTC
user_timezone: America/Guayaquil
event_user_timezone: 2020-11-17 13:00:00-05:00
event_user_timezone.hour: 13
```

However, when rendering the html, with this code:

```
<p class="text-muted font-weight-bold" >
    {{ event.date_start|date:"h:i A" }} ({{ owner_profile.timezone }})
</p>
 <p class="text-muted font-weight-bold">
    {{ event_user_timezone|date:"h:i A" }} {{ logged_user_profile.timezone }}
 </p>
```

both times are displayed as 6pm. Why?

Comment: Did you set `USE_L10N` to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

The date filter is specifically designed to undo what you did, as it is marked as "expects_localtime", which then goes to `django.utils.timezone.template_localtime`.

You don't have to do the things you do in the view, instead you should work with the date filter and the tag [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone), which then sets the correct timezone for a given block.

```html
{% timezone owner_profile.timezone %}
<p class="text-muted font-weight-bold" >
    {{ event.date_start|date:"h:i A" }} ({{ owner_profile.timezone }})
</p>
{% endtimezone %}
{% timezone logged_user_profile.timezone %}
 <p class="text-muted font-weight-bold">
    {{ event.date_start|date:"h:i A" }} {{ logged_user_profile.timezone }}
 </p>
{% endtimezone %}
```